# How to select the largest area of ​a partial dependence (PD) of two features?

Tags: python, dictionary, pdp, xai

[Partial Dependence Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eilnI.png)

In the Partial Dependence plot, we can see that, where the x1 > 0.25 and x2 >= 0.15, we have the biggest area in the plot.. i need a way to get this information without look the plot

I used:

```
pdp=partial_dependence(retrain_pipeline.named_steps['classifier'], X_test_without_low_median, ['x1', 'x2'])
```

and i have the result:

````
    {'average': array([[[0.53756938, 0.53756938, 0.54355124, ..., 0.59259136, 0.55029136, 0.52017778], [0.53756938, 0.53756938, 0.54355124, ..., 0.59259136, 0.55029136, 0.52017778], [0.53082531, 0.53082531, 0.53680717, ..., 0.58229136, 0.53999136, 0.50987778], ..., [0.69637621, 0.69637621, 0.69737621, ..., 0.63123333, 0.60833333, 0.6005    ], [0.67769996, 0.67769996, 0.67869996, ..., 0.61263333, 0.58973333, 0.5819    ], [0.67769996, 0.67769996, 0.67869996, ..., 0.61263333, 0.58973333, 0.5819    ]]]), 'values': [array([0.        , 0.03364426, 0.03870327, 0.03879565, 0.04209536, 0.04214573, 0.04233236, 0.04385038, 0.04592593, 0.04683022, 0.04707106, 0.04837004, 0.04940189, 0.04993555, 0.05014807, 0.05501147, 0.06183098, 0.06351369, 0.06447049, 0.06530872, 0.06573834, 0.06648753, 0.06900972, 0.07765975, 0.07842961, 0.07949964, 0.08837009, 0.09416331, 0.09469922, 0.09829062, 0.10010111, 0.10197684, 0.10315327, 0.11819561, 0.12002853, 0.13697795, 0.14647881, 0.14831436, 0.14912793, 0.15654596, 0.17040449, 0.18358225, 0.19643475, 0.22085183, 0.22216258, 0.23185651, 0.25080282, 0.25977603, 0.28138296, 0.36935399, 0.4296825 , 0.43501151]), array([0.        , 0.02378703, 0.03169297, 0.03373704, 0.04083729, 0.04959665, 0.05100282, 0.05555977, 0.06316509, 0.06995714, 0.07124606, 0.07485143, 0.08086116, 0.08097122, 0.09018592, 0.10147585, 0.10281403, 0.11815467, 0.13221558, 0.13462241, 0.14089637, 0.14504344, 0.14548563, 0.14886247, 0.15170551, 0.15629501, 0.16630413, 0.17038255, 0.18953145, 0.20163417, 0.21190481, 0.21734683, 0.2362917 , 0.23743442, 0.2429823 , 0.24675983, 0.25533671, 0.25966808, 0.27360671, 0.28759964, 0.28992183, 0.30741292, 0.32467602, 0.32627495, 0.33689141, 0.35542858])]}    
    ```

So.. How can I find something like the x1 and x2 intervals that I mentioned at the beginning with this result from the pdp variable?
````